# difference between various import statements in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

```
import sys
from sys import argv
```

I read about about import statement in pydocs. It says it executes in two steps. (1)find a module, and initialize it if necessary; (2) define a name or names in the local namespace (of the scope where the import statement occurs). The first form (without from) repeats these steps for each identifier in the `list`. The form with from performs step (1) once, and then performs step (2) repeatedly.

Here I understood that in first case `sys` module will be initialized as part of 1st step and then it will be made available to local namespace as 2nd step.
But what will happen in case of second import form?
Will `sys` module be initialized as first step and only `argv` function of `sys` module(NO OTHER function) is made available to local namespace.
Because I am not able to call any other functions of `sys` module when I am using second form of import statement. So just want to clarify on it specifically. As if `sys` module has been initialized in from import statement then we should be able to call other functions using `sys`. But that is not working.

```
#import sys
from sys import argv

script, input = argv

print "This was the input entered by command line", input

print sys.path # this is not working giving error name sys is not defined.
```

I am suspecting in case of from import statement `sys` module is not getting initalized, only `argv` function is getting initialized but in that case what does from step performs step(1) once mean pydocs?(Note: I am working on python 2.7)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: There you have mentioned that importing the module doesn't waste anything; the module is always fully imported (into the sys.modules mapping), so wether you use import sys or from sys import argv makes no odds. and also rest of the module will be there then why i am not able to use sys.path. that is my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The import statement **always** initializes the whole module. The modules are stored in the [`sys.modules` dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.modules).

When you use `from sys import argv` the `sys` module is **not** bound locally, only `argv` is. You cannot use the name `sys` in your module, because you didn't import that name.

You can only reach the `sys` module if you imported `sys` separately:

```
from sys import argv

script, input = argv

import sys
print sys.path
```

And you can always access all imported modules by accessing `sys.modules`:

```
from sys import modules

print modules['sys'].path
```

Here I bound the name `modules` to the `sys.modules` dictionary, and through that reference, find the `sys` module, and reference the `path` attribute.

Demo:

```
>>> from sys import modules
>>> modules['sys']
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
>>> sys
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
```

Comment: ok got it now. The link which you shared before in that it was mentioned.The rest of the sys module is still there, whether you use anything else from the module or not. so this line confused me actually. So now i am clear that even if whole module is available until it is not bound to namespace it won't work. for which we need to import  sys  once again