# Import function from module without losing module identifier

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way to import a single function from a module, without losing the module name from the function name. As an example,

```
from os import remove
```

leaves me with a function called 'remove'; it's not clear, elsewhere in the code, that it comes from the `os` module. However, this throws a syntax error:

```
from os import remove as os.remove
```

This is almost satisfactory (and possible):

```
from os import remove as os_remove
```

but again it's not completely clear that this comes from the os module; it would be lovely to keep the dot in if possible

Why do I want to do this? Well, here are the premises which led me to investigate this - if anyone can tell me that any of these are flawed that would be an excellent thing to learn in itself:

- If you're only going to use one function from a module, it's more efficient to only import this than import the whole module.
- If using, say, `os.remove` in your code, it's clearer for it to be labelled as such, so it's transparent to everyone else exactly what this function is and how it will behave. Of course, this will be discernable from the import statement, but seems like it would be useful throughout the code.

If this isn't possible, I'd be interested to learn what stops it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first premise is flawed. There is no difference in importing one function vs the whole module.

In order to import anything from a module, Python must first read, parse and execute the entire module. The only difference in importing one function vs the whole thing is what name gets allocated in the current namespace: in this case, it would be one name for the module, or one name for the function. In other words, no difference at all.

Answer (score 1):

Just import the module:

```
import os
```

and now you can reference `os.remove`

Note that *the whole module is imported* regardless of what name you chose to bind; `from os import remove` will not prevent the rest of the module from being imported. See [difference between various import statements in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671586/difference-between-various-import-statements-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Actually Kenneth Reitz explains importing packages/modules as Python philosophy in the [Python Guide](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/);

**Very bad**

```
[...]
from modu import *
[...]
x = sqrt(4)  # Is sqrt part of modu? A builtin? Defined above?
```

**Better**

```
from modu import sqrt
[...]
x = sqrt(4)  # sqrt may be part of modu, if not redefined in **between
```

**Best**

```
import modu
[...]
x = modu.sqrt(4)  # sqrt is visibly part of modu's namespace
```